# Intermittant/Not Working redirects when using HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, servlets

The solution is using Java and Spring rest API's. When one of my API end points is executed via an API call, the request is handed off to a handler. At this point I'm injecting (@autowired) in the HttpServletResponse object via the constructor.

I am struggling to understand why I'm experiencing the following behavior in which the redirect doesn't always work.

This example shows the failing code.

```java
@Controller
public class ConnectController {

    private final IConnectHandler connectHandler;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    public ConnectController(IConnectHandler handler) {
        this.connectHandler = handler;
    }

    @GetMapping("/redirect")
    public String redirectHandler() {
        this.connectHandler.providerRedirect();
    }
}

@Service
public class ConnectHandler implements IConnectHandler {

    private final HttpServletResponse response;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    public ConnectController(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public String redirectHandler() {
        response.sendRedirect("http://somewhere.com");
    }
}
```

This example shows the minimum required to get working correctly

```java
@Controller
public class ConnectController {

    private final IConnectHandler connectHandler;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    public ConnectController(IConnectHandler handler) {
        this.connectHandler = handler;
    }

// Now inject here and it all starts working
    @GetMapping("/redirect")
    public String redirectHandler(HttpServletResponse response) { 
        this.connectHandler.providerRedirect();
    }
}

@Service
public class ConnectHandler implements IConnectHandler {

    private final HttpServletResponse response;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    public ConnectController(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public String redirectHandler() {
        response.sendRedirect("http://somewhere.com");
    }
}
```

In the specific method I have experiencing this odd behavior within, I'm performing a redirect using the sendRedirect method.

My issue is this seems to be very unreliable and in most cases return a template not found error.

BUT, if I inject the HttpServletResponse into the controller method, everything works as expected, even if I do not use that specific object and continue to use that which is injected into the handler.

I'm fairly new to this framework and I'm sure its due to my limited understanding but if someone could point me in the right direction and provide some insight I would be grateful